# How to ensure the same static pybind11:dict defined in one module is accessed by other modules using that library

Tags: python, c++, bazel, pybind11

I'm trying to build some python modules using pybind11 and Bazel. The key thing is that I need a central dictionary to store information on all modules of a certain type (Foo, Bar in code below). However, the static pybind11::dict that I use to store this information seems to be initialized multiple times, with each module (Foo/Bar) receiving it's own copy of it.

Hence below when I run Registration::register() in the Foo module, and Bar module, I get a different pointer to dict in each instance as shown in the print statement in Registration::register().

I suspected my issue has something to do with how I'm linking the libraries, or how I'm ensuring that the library is shared.

---

In project_name/registration/registration.h:

```
class Registration {
  public:
    static pybind11::dict dict;

    static pybind11::dict& registrations();

    template <typename BaseClass>
    static void register(const char* name);
};

template <typename BaseClass>
void Registration::register(const char* name) {
  pybind11::dict& dict = Registration::registrations();
  pybind11::print(&dict); **// This prints a different pointer in each module!**
  dict[name] = WrapInPyCapsule(some_function<BaseClass>);
};
```

In project_name/registration/registration.cc:

```
pybind11::dict Registration::dict = pybind11::dict();

pybind11::dict& Registration::registrations() {
  return Registration::dict;
}
```

---

In project_name/foo/foo.cc and project_name/bar/bar.cc

```
include "project_name/registration/registration.h"

PYBIND11_MODULE(foo, m) {
    Registration::register("foo") // or "bar" in bar.cc
}
```

---

BAZEL Build File For Registration:

```
pybind_library(
    name = "registration",
    hdrs = ["registration.h"],
    srcs = ["registration.cc"],
)
```

---

BAZEL Build File For Foo:

```
pybind_extension(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = [
        "foo.cc",
    ],
    linkopts = [
        "-ldl",
    ],
    deps = [
        "//project_name/registration/registration",
    ],
)
```

---

BAZEL Build File For Bar:

```
pybind_extension(
    name = "bar",
    srcs = [
        "bar.cc",
    ],
    linkopts = [
        "-ldl",
    ],
    deps = [
        "//project_name/registration/registration",
    ],
)
```

Comment: Is using `JaxCallsRegistration` instead of `Registration` intentional?

Comment: Yup it was thanks! Have fixed it